# No SafeTxGas parameters

Tags: gnosis-safe

According to these info [this](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4738445-advanced-transaction-parameters) and [this](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/a6504a9afdeac186a8cdb29ad68b189523c80eda/docs/safe_tx_gas.md), it looks like there should be `SafeTxGas` parameter, but in my environment, there is not, and `GasLimit` end up zero and transaction always fail.

I'm using v1.3 of Gnosis Safe in Rinkeby environment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the gas limit is 0, it means that we couldn't estimate it because the transaction is failing or there's a bug on our side. You can try to simulate the transaction on Tenderly and check if it's valid.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can estimate it? I usually know the reason by sending tx anyway, and see the revert reason, but Gnosis returns their own message(e,g, 'GS013'). Is there any way I can know the reason(e.g. "Safe math")

Comment: You cannot estimate it if it reverts. You can simulate the transaction on Tenderly to check the error. List of Safe error codes can be found here: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/186a21a74b327f17fc41217a927dea7064f74604/docs/error_codes.md